# How can I define a shorthand alias for a boolean yargs option that negates the option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

Let's say I want to pass my (yargs-enabled) script a boolean option:

```
./foo --secure-but-slow=false
```

`secure-but-slow` should default to true, so only users who know what they're doing choose the insecure option. However, it would be nice for power users to have a shortcut short-option flag, e.g.

```
./foo -i
```

What's the right way to tell yargs that `-i` should set `--secure-but-slow=false`?